# Force close while attaching the video in android MMS

Tags: android, mms

I am trying to attach a video in my mms application. But the application went force close. I am not able find the reason. i can provide the log. Please have a look on this and give me suggestions.

```
07-01 10:11:34.546: WARN/dalvikvm(1064): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4002d560)
07-01 10:11:34.546: INFO/ActivityManager(244): Starting: Intent { act=android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE cmp=jp.co.sharp.android.camera/.videocamera.VideoCamera (has extras) } from pid 1064
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {jp.co.sharp.android.camera/jp.co.sharp.android.camera.videocamera.VideoCamera}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.startActivityForResult(ComposeMessageActivity.java:464)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.addAttachment(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2478)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.access$4800(ComposeMessageActivity.java:157)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity$20.onClick(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2516)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:873)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3632)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1911)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3728)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
07-01 10:11:34.556: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 10:11:34.566: WARN/ActivityManager(244):   Force finishing activity com.android.mms/.ui.ComposeMessageActivity
```

Thanks.

Comment: jp.co.sharp.android.camera/jp.co.sharp.android.camera.videocamera.VideoCamera.. make sure the above class is declared in manifest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite explicit: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {jp.co.sharp.android.camera/jp.co.sharp.android.camera.videocamera.VideoCamera}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Make sure you have that activity in your manifest